# Sliding horizontally in a PDF to go to the next/previous page with a gesture with a Logitech MX Master 2S

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, logitech-mouse

I've had a Logitech MX Master 2S for a couple of weeks now and now that I was viewing a PDF, I realized I could configure some gesture buttons so that I didn't have to reach for my keyboard to zoom in/out or go to the next/previous page. I configured it like so: [Gesture button configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TLTY.png) on my Windows. This allows me to zoom in/out correctly by sliding forward and backward. Nevertheless, I can't find a configuration option that allows me to go to the next/previous page by sliding horizontally. The best that I could find was the option to specify a custom action, which allowed me to mimic the keypress of `AVPAG` and `REPAG` on my keyboard (I believe they are `Page Up` and `Page Down` in an English keyboard) to go back and forth. But this mimics a single press, that is, I can't continuously slide horizontally; I have to let go of my gesture button, press it again, and slide again. Is there such a configuration for this mouse, even if I have to edit something in the registry or anywhere else, that allows me to slide horizontally in a PDF viewer just like how I can zoom in/out when sliding forwards/backwards?

Comment: There are *many* PDF viewers from Adobe, PdfXChange, Sumatra, etc. What works for one might not for another.

Comment: But this does not depend on PDF viewer. It's a configuration option that Logitech offers its users with their software Logitech Options. I couldn't find anything in there that could help me, but there are a ton of options so one could be hiding somewhere. Moreover, I've read posts of people editing stuff in registry to get desired behaviours, which is why I asked here in case anyone knew what I could do specifically for this problem.